# Snapping two objects together via vertex selection

Tags: modeling, snapping

I'm a game developer and I'm using the Christmas break as an excuse to finally learn blender. The 2.8 update is fantastic and I'm enjoying it so far.

However I have a question and I want to know if there is an easier way to do snap two objects together.

[image]

In the image above, I want to know if there is an easier way to snap these objects, aligning by the vertices I have highlighted. I was able to use the vertex snap by closest to achieve this, I'm concerned that repeating this process with a more complicated model will be more difficult. (See image below)

[image]

The best way I could find of doing this is going into edit mode, selecting all verts, then deselecting and reselecting the vert I want to use to snap and then changing the vert snapping parameters to 'active'. This does do what I want (see image below), but it's a lot of steps.

[image]

I'm most familiar with 3DS Max as a modelling tool, and it's fairly simple to mouse over a vert, allowing it to become the 'active' and then dragging to snap to another vert. Is there a similar methodology to this in blender or am I coming at this problem from the wrong angle?

Comment: If you use the 'Active' 'Vertex' option, all selected vertices will transform in such a way as to snap the active vertex to your selected target. I wish that 'Target' sub-panel had been re-labelled 'Source' .. it refers to the component in motion.

Comment: My issue is more complicated than you. I don't even know a way to snap the objects using vertex not even the "not better way"  that you are doing and didn't even understand how you are doing it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I also learned to Snap in 3DS Max and I'm having a hell of a time figuring this out in blender?  The only way that I can figure out how to do it is through a very convoluted set of operations with Shift-S.  I can go to edit mode and select a vertex, snap the 3D cursor to the vertex, exit edit mode, select the 2nd object, go into pivot editing mode, select a vertex, snap the pivot to the vertex, exit pivot editing mode, and then snap the 2nd object to the cursor...phew. There's got to be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest done with [QuickSnap addon](https://github.com/JulienHeijmans/quicksnap)

Comment: .. and soon to be standard in 4.0.. 'B' will locate the source (moving) snap feature in Object Mode.